# Create multivalue bar chart bokeh python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

For the following sample dataframe df2, I want to create bar charts for every row only when there are positive values, using Bokeh.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# create dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': ['Hot', 'Cold', 'Warm', 'Cold'],
                   })
 

 
# create dummy variables
df2=pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Please advise.

Edit.
I found the following example which works

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.transform import dodge
labs = ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3']
vals = ['val_1','val_2','val_3']
my_data = {'labs':labs,
   'val_1':[2,5,11],
   'val_2':[34,23,1],
   'val_3':[25, 34, 23]
}
fig = figure(x_range = labs, plot_width = 300, plot_height = 300)
fig.vbar(x = dodge('labs', -0.25, range = fig.x_range), top = 'val_1',
width = 0.2,source = my_data, color = "green")
fig.vbar(x = dodge('labs', 0.0, range = fig.x_range), top = 'val_2',
width = 0.2, source = my_data,color = "cyan")
fig.vbar(x = dodge('labs', 0.25, range = fig.x_range), top = 'val_3',
width = 0.2,source = my_data,color = "blue")
show(fig)
```

However my data source is pandas dataframe so I am confused how to achieve the outcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll be more likely to get an answer if you show what you have researched and tried with the Bokeh library, and make your question a bit more specific

Comment: Could you specify your question please? What do you want to really? what kind of bar graph? pandas works well with bokeh. You can directly use it or use columndatasource of bokeh